# Android Studio Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb

```
8:41:01 AM Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
8:41:23 AM Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger
8:41:24 AM Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
8:41:26 AM Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
8:41:30 AM Can't bind to local 8604 for debugger
8:41:36 AM Can't bind to local 8605 for debugger
8:41:42 AM Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger
8:41:46 AM Can't bind to local 8608 for debugger
8:41:48 AM Can't bind to local 8610 for debugger
8:41:50 AM Can't bind to local 8613 for debugger
8:41:57 AM Can't bind to local 8622 for debugger
8:42:41 AM Can't bind to local 8628 for debugger
8:41:01 AM Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
8:41:23 AM Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger
8:41:24 AM Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
8:41:26 AM Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
8:41:30 AM Can't bind to local 8604 for debugger
8:41:36 AM Can't bind to local 8605 for debugger
8:41:42 AM Can't bind to loc
```

Answer (score 9):

Also check you [hosts](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts) file.

**host**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

These lines should not be cumented. [hint](http://www.howtogeek.com/118389/how-to-comment-out-and-uncomment-lines-in-a-configuration-file/)

Comment: just delete other useless host record, android studio 2.3 work fine.

Comment: So should these lines be there or not? It's commented by default.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem. My issue was that my hosts file (**/etc/hosts** on macOS) had the following extra localhost entry:

```
10.0.1.12    localhost
```

After deleting that entry, debugger started working!